# What guarantees does UDP give?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

UDP packets obviously can arrive multiple times, not at all and out of order.

But if packets arrive, is it guaranteed, that any call to `recvfrom` and similar functions will return exactly one complete packet the sender sent via `sendto` (or similar)? In other words, is it possible to receive incomplete packets or multiple packets at once? Is it dependent on the OS, or does the standard mandate a certain behavior?

Comment: It is not UDP that gives those guarantees (if any).  It is operating system implementation.  The UDP RFC (standard) only governs what goes "over the wire".

Comment: @StephenC But it would be possible for the UDP RFC to mandate that incomplete packets are never forwarded to higher layers. Just as the TCP RFC mandates that all bytes have to be forwarded in order.

Comment: The question is not whether it would be *possible* for the RFCs to do that.  The question is whether *they actually do that*.  If you look at [RFC 768](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc768), you will see that it does not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, the UDP specification ([RFC 768](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768)) does not specify the behavior of the "interface" between an application program and the OS infrastructure that handles UDP messages.

However, [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recvfrom.html) *does* address this.  The key section of the `recvfrom` spec says this:

> The `recvfrom()` function shall return the length of the message written to the buffer pointed to by the buffer argument. For message-based sockets, such as `SOCK_RAW`, `SOCK_DGRAM`, and `SOCK_SEQPACKET`, the entire message shall be read in a single operation. If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer, and MSG_PEEK is not set in the flags argument, the excess bytes shall be discarded.

Note the use of the word "shall".  Any OS <-> application API that claims to conform to the POSIX spec would be bound by that language.

---

In simple terms, any POSIX compliant `recvfrom` will return one complete UDP message in the buffer provided that the buffer space provided is large enough.  If it is not large enough, "excess" bytes will be discarded.

(Some `recvfrom` implementations support a non-standard `MSG_TRUNC` flag that allows the application to find out the actual message length.  Check the OS-specific manual page for details.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the correct specification. Do you know if windows complies with this too?

Comment: I don't know that.  I expect so though.  An interface that returned fragments of messages would be difficult to use.

Comment: Yes, Windows' [flavor of `recvfrom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recvfrom) conforms to this behavior, too.  A given UDP message can only be received once (unless the `MSG_PEEK` flag is used), and will be truncated discarding excess bytes if it is larger than the receiver's buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The *recv* family of system calls don't behave like that. They do not return *frames* or *packets*, they transfer layer 3 payload bytes stored in the processor's internal receive buffers to the *user applications buffer*. In other words, what ultimately determines how many bytes are passed up is the size of the user's buffer. The behaviour is to try and fill this buffer and if that's not possible to send what data has arrived and if that's not possible then block or return no data depending on how the recv is configured.

From [the recv man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) (my emphasis)

> **If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer,
> excess bytes may be discarded depending on the type of socket the
> message is received from.**

> If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait
> for a message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking (see
> fcntl(2)), in which case the value -1 is returned and the external
> variable errno is set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.  **The receive calls
> normally return any data available, up to the requested amount,
> rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested.**

The one other factor that needs to be taken into account is the internal **recive buffer size**. This is a fixed size and attempting to add more data to an already full buffer can result in loss of data. The value can be set with the SO_RCVBUF flag - from the [socket man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html):

> SO_RCVBUF Sets or gets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes.  The
> kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping
> overhead) when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this doubled
> value is returned by getsockopt(2).  The default value is set
> by the /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default file, and **the maximum
> allowed value is set by the /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max file.
> The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 256.**

Comment: This is interesting. But what if all the buffers are large enough? UDP packets can only be 2^16 bytes large, so it is easy to provide large enough buffers. Can I still get incomplete packets or multiple packets at once? If so, UDP would be very hard to work with, since you would still need to add some kind of framing in your packets...

Comment: typically, receive buffers are FIFO - first in, first out. So you receive the oldest data first. When you implement code to read UDP data, you make sure the socket is blocking and read until there is no more data to be read, keeping the receive buffer as empty as possible. At a lower layer, bytes are essentially transferred sequentially - for example,in ethernet (and eg 4g), only one frame can be "in the cable" or in the air at a time, so you never really get "multiple packets at once". Research ethernet for more information.

Comment: None of this applies to UDP.

Comment: it doesn't, because UDP is a layer 3 thing, but layers 1 & 2 ensure there is no so thing as "receiving multiple packets at once". That's the point.